# Highcharts legend paging position

Tags: html, highcharts, legend

I have a lot of legends in one of my high charts. I found a way to render this is using the navigation option inside legends.

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#legend.navigation

```
navigation: {
            activeColor: '#3E576F',
            animation: true,
            arrowSize: 12,
            inactiveColor: '#CCC',
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: '#333',
                fontSize: '12px'
            }
        }
```

But the navigation has very minimal options in it.

Can i position the legend according to my need, like at the bottom of the div?
Can i have a horizontal paging scroll instead of a vertical one?

Comment: i think you can use HTML navigation and mayber there it possible to tweak it a little more as you need? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.useHTML

Comment: `useHTML` option disables navigation. These are only option to customize navigation. However, you can position legend at the bottom of the div: http://jsfiddle.net/jx8oo6ex/ (see `maxHeight` option too!).  Horizontal paging isn't supported.

Answer (score 1):

To position legend at the bottom, I added maxHeight and changed layout to horizontal (as this suits my needs best), etc:

```
legend: {
        layout: 'horizontal',//change to horizontal
        //align: 'right',//removed alignment
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        maxHeight: 50,//this was the key property to make my legend paginated
        //y: 40,//remove position
        navigation: {
            activeColor: '#3E576F',
            animation: true,
            arrowSize: 12,
            inactiveColor: '#CCC',
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                color: '#333',
                fontSize: '12px'
            }
        }
    },
```